# Using header and its implementation in an another class?

Tags: c++, header-files

How can I use a header file and it's implementation?

A.h

```
class ClassA { 
int value;
ClassA();
}
```

ClassA.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
ClassA(){
this->value = 0;
}
```

ClassB.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
ClassB(){
this->value = 1;
}
int main(){
//I want to create an Object of ClassA.
ClassA ca = new ClassA(); //but this is not working
}
```

Hi, I have two headers and two source files.

I want to create an object of ClassA in ClassB. How is this possible?
I get always the following error:

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "ClassA::ClassA()", referenced from:
      _main in ClassB-9b2a5e.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Where's the header for `ClassB`?

Comment: `ClassA::ClassA() { ... }` should be your ClassA.cpp. Also `new ClassA()` returns `ClassA*` (note: pointer)

Comment: Its still not working! :/

Comment: Off-topic:  You don't need to use the `this->` syntax.  Only use it when you can't name your method parameters differently than the data members.

Comment: You don't need to use `new` to create objects or instances of a class.  C++ != Java, C++ != C#.

Comment: If I do this: ClassA a1; I get the same error. :/